# How to conditionally add widgets to a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-statements, flutter-widget, flutter-listview

In flutter, widgets such as `Row`/`ListView`/`Stack` don't handle null children. So if we want to conditionally add widgets as children I usually do the following:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    foo == 42 ? Text("foo") : Container(),
  ],
);
```

But this feels weird to add an empty container.

Another solution is a `where` filter :

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    foo == 42 ? Text("foo") : null,
  ].where((t) => t != null).toList(),
);
```

This solves the empty container problem but we still have an ugly ternary and it is tiresome to write.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Since Dart 2.2, new syntaxes supports this natively:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    if (foo != null) Text(foo),
    Bar(),
  ],
);
```

---

This problem is currently debated on github [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17862#issuecomment-416581089).

But for now, you can use dart `sync*` functions:

```
Row(
  children: toList(() sync* {
    if (foo == 42) {
      yield Text("foo");
    }
  }),
);
```

where `toList` is:

```
typedef Iterable<T> IterableCallback<T>();

List<T> toList<T>(IterableCallback<T> cb) {
  return List.unmodifiable(cb());
}
```

---

Not only it solves the conditional addition problem; it also allows for a "spread operator" thanks to `yield*`. Example:

```
List<Widget> foo;

Row(
  children: toList(() sync* {
    yield Text("Hello World");
    yield* foo;
  }),
);
```

Comment: Brilliant! How about `List.of(_buildChildren())`, where `_buildChildren` is a `sync*` method?

Comment: Works too. But it's a bit more boring to use when you want to pass arguments. The closure make it easier

Comment: Can I use Dart 2.2 syntax to add several items at once with the same condition?

Answer (score 7):

The new Dart syntax allows 'if' in lists, which leads to this simple solution:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    if (foo == 42) Text("foo"),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
Row(
    children: [
        if (_id == 0) ...[
          Container()
        ] else if(_id == 1)...[
          Text("Hello")
        ] else ...[
          SizedBox(width: 20)
        ],
    ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler version I use:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text("always included"),
    skipNulls([
      icon,
      label,
    ]),
  ],
);

skipNulls<T>(List<T> items) {
  return items..removeWhere((item) => item == null);
}
```