# Flutter how to refactor list of widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to render widgets on `Stack` and there is `enum` and with that state I want to render different widgets except for background image like this. [image].

`Stack` looks like this now

```
new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Image.network(
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536226078409-fb25e1ed23b9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=51ea5572bb7bbdf19e616f3550fccd9d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      // render widgets here.
    ],
  ),
```

Then I want to render based on the `enum` state. 
So, code would be like this.

```
 List<Widget> listOfWidget() {
    return [];
  }

 new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image.network(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536226078409-fb25e1ed23b9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=51ea5572bb7bbdf19e616f3550fccd9d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          listOfWidget(),
        ],
      ),
```

However error says

> The element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

I totally understand what's going on but I don't know how to fix this.
How can I refactor this?

Comment: Take a look at the second part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060876/how-to-conditionally-add-widgets-to-a-list/52060877#52060877

Comment: Thank you for comment. If I put Stack on Stack, is this bad thing? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

The `children` property in a `Stack` is a `List<Widget>`.

You give it a value of `[Widget, List<Widget>]` which is a list with heterogeneous elements (first is a `Widget`, second elements is a `List`). So your given value is not a `List<Widget>` like it is necessary but rather a `List<dynamic>`. The second element in your `List<dynamic>` is a `List<Widget>` which needs to be assigned to a `Widget` which is not possible, hence the error.

You can do something like this:

```
List<Widget> listOfWidget() {
    return [];
}

new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
        [new Image.network(
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536226078409-fb25e1ed23b9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=51ea5572bb7bbdf19e616f3550fccd9d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        )],
        listOfWidget(),
    ].expand((list) => list).toList();,
),
```

Notice that you put the original image in an List as well.
So basically this will flatten your list to create a final `List<Widget>`.