# How to show icon by value in Flutter Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application like this:

[image]

I also have a Firebase Firestore build like this:

[image]

Now let's get to the problem.

---

First of all, I am making a to-do application. The top image shows how the tasks in Firestore look.

I added a value named important to each of the tasks I added to Firestore. This indicates the urgency of the task.

Now my question is this: I would like to point out the important information in the documents I use as part of these tasks.

[image]

The `label_important` icon in this view indicates whether the task is important or not. I added this icon to all of them as a test.

I want to pull `important: true` values ​​from Firestore and place label_important next to only `true` ones. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
Container(
  height: 500,
  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return InkWell(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 5,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline, size: 28,),
                    onTap: () {
                    },
                  ),
                  title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["title"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        child: Icon(Icons.label_important), // important: true <<<<<<<
                        onTap: () {
                          //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => edit(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["title"].toString(), snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["content"].toString(), snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["id"].toString())));
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10,),
                      InkWell(
                        child: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 28,),
                        onTap: () {
                          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(user.uid).doc(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["id"].toString()).delete();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            );
          },
        );
      }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    ),
),
```

[image]

---

Let me give an example:

[image]

[image]

The `important` value of the task whose `title` is "Flüt çal" is `true`. Then this task is important. And `label_important` icon should appear in this task.

And when we look at the task whose `title` is "Okula git", the `important` value is `false`. So this mission was not important. Then the `label_important` icon will not appear.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you asking [how to conditionally add a widget to the `children` list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060876/how-to-conditionally-add-widgets-to-a-list)?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Yes, it has the same logic. But I couldn't because I wanted to make changes according to the item in the list. I normally know the production on the subject you posted.

Comment: To it seems like exactly what Frank suggested, you conditionally want to add the icon

Answer (score 1):

To conditionally add the icon, I'd do something like:

```
children: [
  if (snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["title"].toString() == "Flüt çal") InkWell(
    child: Icon(Icons.label_important), // important: true <<<<<<<
    onTap: () {
      ...
    },
  ),
  SizedBox(width: 10,),
  ...
```

Also see: [How to conditionally add widgets to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060876/how-to-conditionally-add-widgets-to-a-list)